# Display only data on axis that is present in the figure

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, formatting, xticks

[image: example]

How do I hide the `32.` and `Jun, 14 2020` tickers that are not getting used. They don't exist in the data I provided.

I'm setting locators like this:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the y axis you should use:

```
plt.gca().set_ylim([27, 31])
```

The same for the x axis, but you should use the date format. Can you provide the line of code where you do the plot?
As an example, if your x axis data are located in a `'Date'` column of a `df` dataframe, you could use:

```
plt.gca().set_xlim([df['Date'].iloc[0], df['Date'].iloc[-1]])
```